# Testing for element absence in a matrix, reporting to new vector if absent

Tags: r, if-statement, matrix

I've got a matrix (neutral.0 or orig.matrix) that contains the letters a - e (species.v), as characters, randomly distributed. I 
then replace a random element of the matrix with another random element from the same matrix, on a loop for a few repeats
(in this test matrix 100), which is the basic principal of what the program I'm running is. As the elements are random, 
there may be a dominant letter, e.g. A, that replaces another, e.g. E, after a number of repeats. I know how to check for whether the contents of species.v 
are present in neutral.0 (using %in%, though have also read that is.element is possible). However I can't figure out how to convert
the true/false output to reporting that the element is now absent.

My code is:

```
##Create Species Vector
species.v<-letters[1:5]
as.character(species.v)
##Check species Vector
species.v


#Matrix creation (Random)
orig.neutral<- matrix(sample(species.v,25,replace=TRUE),
                        nrow=5,
                        ncol=5)
##Check neutral.matrix
orig.neutral


##For loop and check for absence, &in& or is.element()
neutral.v0 <- orig.neutral
for (i in 1:100) {{
  neutral.v0[sample(length(neutral.v0),1)]<-as.character(sample(neutral.v0,1))}
  ifelse()species.v %in% neutral.v0=="FALSE",....)  
}
```

The "...." is where I can't figure out how to make it return which letter is now absent. I'm not even sure if I've used the right function. I thought ifelse might work, but I've hit a wall in getting it to report something, and also in whether what would be reported is the "FALSE" or the actual element that is now "extinct"

Further, after this, I could do with almost the reverse of the code.

I'm going to have a bit of code the causes "speciation", e.g. instead of replacing an a with an e, a will "become" a2, or something similar. While I've not figured out that exactly yet, I'd planned on using a similar "ifelse" function to tell me when an event like that (a to a2, or e to e2 or something) occurred.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `ifelse()` with no content is not a thing; neither is `&in&`. Also, fyi, you can do `(species.v<-letters[1:5])` to both assign to an object and print it.

Comment: Maybe you want `setdiff`?

Comment: Also, `as.character(species.v)` does nothing permanent unless you assign it: `species.v <- as.character(species.v)`.

Comment: Yeah sorry, that was something lost in editing, it was originally ifelse(somestuff that didn't work at all), and I was just writing and testing the &in& section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to know what letters are in `species.v` but not in `neutral.v0`, then `setdiff(species.v, neutral.v0)` should do it. Using @Imo's data and set up, after the `"b"`'s are all removed,

```
setdiff(species.v, neutral.v0)
[1] "b"
```

If you want to see results for all species:

```
data.frame(species = species.v, still_alive = species.v %in% neutral.v0)
  species still_alive
1       a        TRUE
2       b       FALSE
3       c        TRUE
4       d        TRUE
5       e        TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for.  

Would it work in reverse for when new species are added (from a third list) also?

Comment: `setdiff` is pretty well documented and makes sense too - it gives all the elements of the first argument that are not in the second argument. Check out the documentation for other set operations as well.

Comment: But I have no idea what you mean by "work in reverse... from a third list".

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use `match` on the list of species, species.v.  Here is the setup that you will need to tweak a bit.

```
# set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(1234)
orig.neutral<- matrix(sample(species.v,25,replace=TRUE),
                        nrow=5,
                        ncol=5)

neutral.v0 <- orig.neutral

# show first matching positions of the orginal species.v
match(species.v, neutral.v0)
```

Note that these positions go down the columns, so 8 (species b) corresponds to column 2, row 3.

```
# now fill remove all bs
neutral.v0[neutral.v0 == "b"] <- "c"
match(species.v, neutral.v0)
```

The match for b returns NA.

So you could use

```
myMatch <- match(species.v, neutral.v0)
names(myMatch) <- species.v
print(names(myMatch)[is.na(myMatch)])
```

and the myMatch vector will store the extinct species. It is reproduced in every iteration, which is not ideal, but is presumably fairly small.

Comment: Thank you, I've used @Gregor's solution involving the setdiff function, but your method of reporting it is exactly what I needed!

Comment: Sure Thing, @Mike. `setdiff` is a great function.